# Menu Items are not displaying on Action Bar when ActionbarActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I am making an android application.In that application contains navigation drawer menu.For supporting to lower versions of android I added Appcompat library.For that I extended my class  to ActionbarActivity.I need options menu towards right to the screen on action bar but I am getting options menu always from bottom of the screen.Same code I added to normal activity it is showing fine but in ActionbaActivity it is not showing.Please help me

Comment: Did you test it on emulator or real device? Does the device have physical menu button?

Comment: I tested in samsung s2 and options menu is working fine in remaining activities except in actionbaractivity it is showing from the bottom